# How to enable hardware acceleration for web browser

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, hardware, browser

Is there any way I can enable hardware acceleration, for web browsers, in Ubuntu? It's annoying to watch YouTube videos and have my CPU doing all the work when my GPU does nothing.

I know there is a workaround with Chromium available here, [How To Enable Hardware Acceleration In Chromium On Ubuntu Or Linux Mint (VA-API Patched PPA Builds](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-enable-hardware-accelerated.html))

I tried it but it didn't work for me.

I found out that Chrome will let you enable hardware acceleration from flags, but if you check in [chrome://media-internals](http://chrome://media-internals) the video decoder used to decode videos is not MojoVideoDecoder (the GPU), it uses instead the CPU decoding. In [chrome://gpu](http://chrome://gpu) it will still show that it's using hardware acceleration, but it is in fact not.

After a long time of searching I came to the conclusion that it is not currently possible to have Hardware Acceleration in Chrome (current version 88.0).

Is there any way to have hardware acceleration in Ubuntu 20.04? The browser does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying it multiple times I found out that the guide [How To Enable Hardware Acceleration In Chromium On Ubuntu Or Linux Mint (VA-API Patched PPA Builds](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-enable-hardware-accelerated.html) actually works. Pay close attention to Step n.7 and it should work fine.

To check if it works for you:

1. Go on Youtube and start a video.
2. Go inside [chrome://media-internals](http://chrome://media-internals) and look for the tab that has `(kPlay)` under it. It represents the video that is currently playing. Click on it.
3. Look for `kVideoDecoderName`. If it is `"FFmpegVideoDecoder"`, the Hardware Acceleration is not working. If it is `MojoVideoDecoder`, you're using Hardware Acceleration.

Another way to check if it works is to open Chrome and Chromium on the same Youtube video. Play them one at a time and check your CPU usage. If you did everything right Chromium should have a considerably lower CPU usage. (Just so you can get the idea, for me Chromium with Hardware Acceleration was using around 18%-20% of CPU, while Chrome without Hardware Acceleration was using around 40%-45%, sometimes with peaks of 60%).

Just as a precaution I suggest to also follow this guide [How to Turn Hardware Acceleration On and Off in Chrome](https://www.lifewire.com/hardware-acceleration-in-chrome-4125122). I know it is for Chrome, but it should work the same on Chromium.

Comment: After many hours trying with the latest stable versions of everything (FF, Chromium, Chrome, etc.) nothing worked AT ALL for actually getting videos decoded using hardware. The about://gpu says it should be decoding with hardware but it doesn't (as evidenced in the media pane for both Netflix and YT).

Comment: The guide says that it only works with chromium-beta or chromium-dev (no stable versions will work).